# How to pass variable in file() of terraform

Tags: file, variables, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

It is required to create cloudfront public key using terraform, Here public key is separate based on environment and its stored as {env_name}.pem in directory name public-key-cf.
env_name can be dev,stage,prod.

To achieve this below terraform block is used:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_public_key" "documents-signing-key" {
  name        = "cf-public-key"
  comment     = "Public Key"
  encoded_key = file("${path.module}/public-key-cf/"${var.environment}".pem)"
}
```

I am getting error as :

```
This character is not used within the language.
```

How to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have syntax issues within your code and have used quotes in the wrong places. Please refer to [String Templates](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#string-templates) for string interpolations in terraform.

- This is the structure I have used to simulate your query.

```bash
.
├── dependencies.tf
├── file_function_variable.tf
├── main.tf
└── public-key-cf
    └── dev.pub
```

- Where file_function_variable.tf is the one where we focus mostly.

```
## File function within a sting input (multiple string interpolation).
resource "aws_security_group" "file_function_variable" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic with ${file("${path.module}/public-key-cf/${var.environment}.pub")}"
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_tls"
  }
}

## usage of explicit file function.
resource "aws_cloudfront_public_key" "documents-signing-key" {
  name        = "cf-public-key"
  comment     = "Public Key"
  encoded_key = file("${path.module}/public-key-cf/${var.environment}.pub")
}

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) Environment for the deployment"
  default     = "dev"
}
```

- The above code has generated the below plan, to verify how will it look like.

```bash
➜  stackoverflow tf plan                                                                                         <aws:sre>

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the
following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_cloudfront_public_key.documents-signing-key will be created
  + resource "aws_cloudfront_public_key" "documents-signing-key" {
      + caller_reference = (known after apply)
      + comment          = "Public Key"
      + encoded_key      = <<-EOT
            ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAII3EZdb2OUzuMtgxCp5nyR3SmXs1Fml1Z6/kk1cyEuWf
        EOT
      + etag             = (known after apply)
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + name             = "cf-public-key"
      + name_prefix      = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_security_group.file_function_variable will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "file_function_variable" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = <<-EOT
            Allow TLS inbound traffic with ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAII3EZdb2OUzuMtgxCp5nyR3SmXs1Fml1Z6/kk1cyEuWf
        EOT
      + egress                 = (known after apply)
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = (known after apply)
      + name                   = "allow_tls"
      + name_prefix            = (known after apply)
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags                   = {
          + "Name" = "allow_tls"
        }
      + tags_all               = {
          + "Name" = "allow_tls"
        }
      + vpc_id                 = (known after apply)
    }
```

Conclusion:

As mentioned in another answer, it's better to use plugins/extensions while working with terraform.
For VSCode there is an official [HashiCorp.terraform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform) plugin which supports syntax highlighting and much more.

Answer (score 2):

```
encoded_key = file("${path.module}/public-key-cf/"${var.environment}".pem)"
```

It seems to me that you made a syntactical mistake by placing the quotes in the wrong place, I think you meant to write:

```
encoded_key = file("${path.module}/public-key-cf/${var.environment}.pem")
```

If it's the same case in your code that's likely the reason behind that rather cryptic looking error message.

Consider installing a plugin for syntax checks if you haven't yet, it simplifies writing code in terraform (and in general too) by a lot.